# Why not having just one ServiceImpl for all the RPCs?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I am developing a Java GWT-GAE project that is becoming big enough, and I am facing some problems I didn't have some LOCs ago.

I have several methods in the ServiceImpl classes that I need to call directly from other ServiceImpl classes and by RPCs as well. I think it's better to avoid declarations like Service s = new ServiceImpl(), so I thought to move the methods bodies in appropriate server side classes and let the methods in the ServiceImpl classes call them. Would it be the right solution or are there specific patterns to follow?
If it is, wouldn't it be better to have just one ServiceImpl that wraps all the RPC methods?
The client is becoming a little slow, and I think it's because I have several declarations like this: public static final *ServiceAsync *Service = GWT.create(*Service.class);

I hope I've been clear.
Thanks in advance.

Antonio

Comment: Sounds like you have the right idea. Move those methods you want to call directly out to a separate class. You should not be creating ServiceImpl objects yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Server side implementations, consider using [GWT-SL (Server Library)](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-sl/) which allows you to integrate GWT with Spring. Your Service implementation classes become simple Pojos and you don't worry about creating them, just let Spring worry about that!

For creating Service instances in the client side, use this pattern (inside the *Service interface) to ensure you only create Services once as singletons:

```
/**
 * Utility class for simplifying access to the instance of async service.
 */
public static class Util {
    private static UserServiceAsync instance;
    public static UserServiceAsync getInstance(){
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = GWT.create(UserService.class);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

To create the Service on the client-side:

```
private UserServiceAsync userService = UserService.Util.getInstance();
```